# How do you write a .feather file into GCS?

Tags: python, dataframe, google-cloud-storage, feather

Previously worked on .csv files which was straightforward to upload to GCS

For csv I would do the following, which works:

```
blob = bucket.blob(path)
blob.upload_from_string(dataframe.to_csv(), 'text/csv')
```

I am trying to do the same i.e. write the dataframe as a .feather file in bucket

```
blob = bucket.blob(path)
blob.upload_from_string(dataframe.reset_index().to_feather(), 'text/feather')
```

However, this fails saying to_feather() requires a fname. Any suggestions/guidance on where I went wrong would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

upload_from_string works for the to_csv() method because the ‘path’ parameter is optional. When no path is provided, the result is returned as a string. On the other hand, the `to_feather()` method requires a path specified. So you should store the feather file and then upload the feather file into GCS.
Refer the code below:

```
dataFrame.reset_index().to_feather(FILE PATH)

bucket_name = "BUCKET-NAME"
source_file_name = "FILE PATH"
destination_blob_name = "GCS Object Name"

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```